# A question about the incompleteness theorems

Tags: logic

I have a question regarding the proof of corollary 2.2.4 in "The Incompleteness Theorems" (page 8 in this document https://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/smorynski.pdf). Why does $S \vdash Con_T \to \neg  Pr_T(\neg Con_T \to \Lambda)$ imply $S \vdash Con_T \to Con_{T+\neg Con_T}$?

Answer (score 2):

A bit earlier it says that $\Lambda$ denotes a contradictory statement (usually we use $\bot$ for this). So that means that $\neg \operatorname{Con}_T \to \Lambda$ would say "from $\neg \operatorname{Con}_T$ we can derive a contradiction". So $\neg \operatorname{Pr}_T(\ulcorner \neg \operatorname{Con}_T \to \Lambda \urcorner)$ means "we cannot prove in $T$ that from $\neg \operatorname{Con}_T$ we can derive a contradiction" and this is precisely saying that $T + \neg \operatorname{Con}_T$ is consistent.

Comment: But, how do you show this formally?

Comment: @arm46 There is not really a precise definition of $\operatorname{Con}_{T + \neg \operatorname{Con}_T}$ in the document you linked. To make it all precise you could just take this to be the definition. If you want to make things more precise, you'd have to go into detail about how $\operatorname{Pr}_T$ is defined and what happens when you add axioms to $T$.